# $L^p$-convergence when composed with a smooth function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

Let $L\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be a smooth function, such that $L\circ f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$ for any $f\in L^p(\mathbb R)$. Now if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\mathbb R)$, does it implies that $L\circ f_n\to L\circ f$ in $L^p$?

Comment: Try to show that $\frac {L(x)} x$ is bounded.

Comment: Why should it be the case?

Comment: @Son This is a simplify question of what I am trying to understand. In general, when $L:W^{k,p}\to L^p$ is a non linear differential operator, I want to know if it is continuous and if it's Frechet derivatives are continuous.

Comment: I see your point. My question was for Kavi